# TypeError: draw_networkx_nodes() got an unexpected keyword argument 'with_labels'

Tags: python, tkinter, networkx

I am new to using Tkinter and networkx python libraries i want to plot a graph but i got the following error

[image]

```
def plot_actual():
    pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(40, 30),dpi=100)
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos,with_labels=True,ax=ax) // LINE 601
    labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos)
    nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=labels)
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edge_labels=labels) // LINE 605
    ax.tick_params(left=True, bottom=True, labelleft=True, labelbottom=True)
    path=('ActualGraph.png')
    plt.savefig(path)
    img = PImage.open(path)
    img.show()
    return
```

i got an error on nx.draw_networkx_nodes but i did not get the actual reason for this

1st error i got in line 627 (i mention the line in code snippet too)

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry('1200x900')

my_font = Font(family="Times New Roman", size=20, weight="bold" )
Label(root,  text="" ,font=my_font).pack()
Label(root,  text="Select A .txt File From Your System" ,font=my_font).pack()
btn1 = Button(root, text ='Open', command = lambda:open_file())
btn1.pack(pady = 20)
btn2 = Button(root, text ='SeeActualGraph',command = lambda:plot_actual()) //LINE 627
btn2.pack(pady = 20)
```

if anyone know what's the problem please let me know

Comment: The command `draw_networkx_edge_labels` that adds edge labels to a drawing of a graph is described [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edge_labels.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edge_labels).

Comment: The command `draw_networkx_edges` does not draw the edge labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that the line `nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edge_labels=labels)` has been given an invalid keyword argument.

`nx.draw_networkx_edges` can't be called with edge_labels=labels.

I'm  not very experienced with networkx, but my guess is that you have already given all the edges labels with the previous line, so just calling `nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos)` might work.

Also the traceback isn't a list of errors. You only got one error, the traceback lists all the calls that are on the stack. For your case, the error occurred when you tried line 605, line 605 was called in turn by line 627, which was called in turn by line 1892.

Comment: Then what's the method to call them?

Comment: Thanks remove all these with_label and with_edges. now it works